# Sharepoint Online TeamSite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, web-part, comments

I want to create comment box to my Web Part Page like the picture[image]. 
I use team site template.

Any idea?

**P/S:** I can use SharePoint Designer and My SharePoint Online sever is 2013.

Comment: Please provide more information on your question. In each site pages for modern UI team site collection, Microsoft has provided comment section.

Comment: @DikeshGandhi, but he's not using a modern page. He's using a web part page. That's what he says in the question.

Comment: Trung, your question is very broad. A web part page typically contains web parts with list or library views. How does a comment fit into that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Modern pages then it is Out of Box available.

If you are using classic page then, you can add NoteBoard control at page layout.

To add, Edit the page layout in sharepoint designer and add it after `<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField` Tag.

```
<SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentWebPart id="noteboard" ChromeType="None" runat="server" />
```

Limitation:

1. It has been deprecated fron UI but from designer you can use it.
2. Multilevel/Hierarchical reply not possible.